# How to create a case from email?

Tags: email2case

I have configured my email-to-case settings but when i send an email to the specific email address that was defined by Salesforce, it creates an "Unresolved task" instead of a case.

Could it be doing that because i am not defining the required fields in the email so the case could not be created i.e it's lacking account name for an example... The only things that are passed on from the email to the created unresolved task are the title (email subject), description (email body) and attachments (email attachments).

Is there a way to define things like account name, contact name, type, product, etc, when sending the email-to-case?  I could not find any specific information about this, i only found general guides on how to set up the feature and i believe that i have already done that.

So the bottom line is, can you create a case from an email? If so, how is it done exactly? And, could it not be working for me because i am not defining required fields in the email so it creates an unresolved task?

Comment: 1) If the email address maps to an existing Contact w/ parent Account, then E2C will associate the Case to that Account - otherwise, the Case is created w/o a lookup value to Account.  2) There is very little configuration available for E2C - Case Origin, Recordtype - see E2C settings. everything else requires apex/visual flow/process builder

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this [salesforce guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_To_Email_Services_on_Force.com). You will get clear Idea.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to create from email in salesforce, Since you have tried using “Set up Email To Case” option in salesforce , you can follow the following step by step guide
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000006097&type=1

You should probably add the rules to get the account name, contact, product and type.